# Clever aggregating of tuples in C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I am processing a complex query in parallel. From the called methods I get a lot of `Tuple<IEnumerable<Object>, int>` objects. I would like to aggregate them quickly, but probably .Aggregate (code below) is not the best option. What is the right way to do it?

```
public static Tuple<IEnumerable<Object>, int> Parse(Object obj)
{
    var ieo = new List<Object>();
    var x = 5;
    return new Tuple<IEnumerable<Object>, int>(ieo, x);
}

public static void Query(List<Object> obj)
{
    var result = obj
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(o => Parse(o))
        . // do something to aggregate this quickly and get a tuple of:
          // - flattened IEnumerable<Object>
          // - summed up all second items
}
```

And my aggregate suggestion, which probably is very slow and looks terribly. But works.

```
        .Aggregate((t1, t2) => new Tuple<IEnumerable<Object>, int>(t1.Item1.Concat(t2.Item1), t1.Item2 + t2.Item2));
```

Comment: If it works, what makes you think it isn't the best option?  Have you profiled it to see if it is indeed slow or not?

Comment: I am wondering if making `Aggregate((t1, t2) => t1.Concat(t2))` isn't stupid, since all of them are in fact `IEnumerable`.

Comment: `t1` and `t2` are of type `Tuple<IEnumerable<Object>, int>` which does not have a `Concat` method defined for it.  You could create an extension method called `Concat` that encapsulates your code if you are only worried with how it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write custom flattener.

```
public static Tuple<IEnumerable<T>, int> MagicFlatten<T>(
  this IEnumerable<Tuple<IEnumerable<T>, int>> tupleCrap) 
{
   var item1 = tupleCrap.SelectMany(x => x.Item1);
   var item2 = tupleCrap.Sum(x => x.Item2);
   return new Tuple<...>(item1, item2);
}
```

and later you can use it:

```
.AsParallel()
.Select(o => Parse(o))
.MagicFlatten();
```

Comment: This needs to be `static` for it to work as an extension method.